# Can someone help me about this icon design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon

How are you?
This is my first work. please help me about this icon design. does it have problem?
Thank you
icon picture :

[image]

Comment: Hi Tooraj and welcome to GDSE. I don't think this is really the right place for critique of work – this might be more suited to The Ink Spot (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240)

Comment: Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682) and see whether you can make yours fit those. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex worth noting that you need 20 rep to talk in chat, apart from that you're right that chat would be a better place for critique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of an icon is to be a visual symbol that is used as a mnemonic device to denote a complicated object in a simplified way, so avoid unnecessary details in the icon as they can be distracting.

- It would be better to use just one object in the first icon instead of two objects.
- The second, third and fifth icons have unnecessary small detailed mechanical details like handles that distract the viewer from the sense of the icon. If the object needs to have a handle, the handle should be portrayed in a more simplified way.
- The fourth icon looks like three objects have been stacked together. If the objects must be depicted in a stack, it's not necessary to be elaborate in portraying the details of each individual object in the stack.
- For the color the scheme, your choice of colors might be dictated by the constraints of the design, but it may be possible to elaborate on the color scheme without fundamentally changing it. Take for example the cover of the album Transatlanticism by dcfc.